# EC2 EMR not executing issues spark-submit not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I have created a `sh` file in haddop session in my master EMR to execute a Spark job.

the execution file looks pretty much like usual:

> spark-submit s3://bucket/file.sh

Now, I'm trying to create a cron job to execute the script automatically certain frequency. Well, after a research I notice that EC2 AMI requires create a file *without* extension in the path: `/etc/cron.d/schedule` and then the `schedule` file might content the expected execution so I did it:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
#PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PATH=/home/hadoop/
MAILTO=hadoop
HOME=/home/hadoop/

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed


*/20 11-22 * * * root /home/hadoop/file.sh > report.log
```

I specified before the user `root`  in my `scheduler` file the username `hadoop` but after ask in AWS support they address me to set it up as `root` the thing is that now I'm getting the following error message from the cron log:

```
From: root@ip-10-10-1-240.ec2.internal (Cron Daemon)
To: hadoop@ip-10-10-1-240.ec2.internal
Subject: Cron <root@ip-10-10-1-240> /home/hadoop/file.sh > update.log
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/bash>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/home/hadoop/>
X-Cron-Env: <MAILTO=hadoop>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/hadoop/>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=root>

/home/hadoop/file.sh: line 6: spark-submit: command not found
```

I suppose the root doesnt have set the SPARK environment variables and this is why is not able to understand `spark-submit`. As you know is slightly sensitive change and play around the environment variables in EMR. I dont want to screw up anything so if someone has an idea how to face this issue I appreciate the feedback.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you override `PATH` with `PATH=/home/hadoop/`? That's not where `spark-submit` is located. If you don't specify a full path for an executable, it's looked up in the directories specified in the `PATH` environment variable.

Run `which spark-submit` in a normal shell and it will tell you where `spark-submit` is located. Make sure that directory is included in `PATH`. For example:

```
PATH=/home/hadoop:/usr/bin
```

You probably want to keep the original `PATH` so other scripts and `spark-submit` itself can find basic executables like `ls` and friends.

Comment: cehcking: PATH=/home/hadoop:/usr/bin I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did was add `hadoop` as executor user and that's it :)

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
#PATH=/home/hadoop/:/usr/bin
MAILTO=hadoop
HOME=/home/hadoop/

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed


*/20 11-22 * * *  hadoop  /home/hadoop/file.sh > reportlog
10 11-23 * * *  hadoop /home/hadoop/file2.sh > updatelog
```